# Boyer–Lindquist coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

In the Kerr solution to the vacuum Einstein Equation written in [Boyer–Lindquist coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates). Because it is not spherical polar coordinates, $r$ ranges from 0 to infinity does not cover all the space, does it mean the space inside the ring singularity of radius a cannot be described by the Kerr solution?

Comment: ring singularity forms at r=0 and theta=pi/2.so we have only phi coordinates left.there are analytic continuation after r=0 then r is negative.but in that other space there are no horizon because rho cannot be zero. and there are also some closed time like curves.